# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli, select

Полный код ошибки:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   /home/a1713593/public_html/Projects/PHP Lovers
>   Blog/libraries/Database.php on line 35

Что я пытаюсь выполнить:

```
//Create DB Object
$db = new Database();

//Create Query
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";

//Run Query
$posts = $db->select($query);
```

Сам файл Database.php:

```
<?php
class Database{
    public $host            = DB_HOST;
    public $username    = DB_USER;
    public $password    = DB_PASS;
    public $db_name     = DB_NAME;

    public $link;
    public $error;

    /*
     * Class Constructor
     */
    public function  __consrtuct(){
        //Call Connect Function
        $this->connect();
    } 

    /*
     * Connector
     */
     private function connect(){
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
        if(!$this->link){
            $this->error = "Connection Failed: ".$this->link->connect_error;
            return false;
        }
     }

     /*
      * Select
      */

      public function select($query){
        $result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            return $result;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
      }

     /*
      * Insert
      */
      public function insert($query){
        $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

        //Validate Insert
        if($insert_row){
            header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Added'));
            exit();
        } else{
            die('Error : ('. $this->link->errno . ') '. $this -> link -> error);
        }
      }

      /*
      * Update
      */
      public function update($query){
        $update_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

        //Validate Insert
        if($update_row){
            header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Updated'));
            exit();
        } else{
            die('Error : ('. $this->link->errno . ') '. $this -> link -> error);
        }
      }

      /*
      * Delete
      */
      public function delete($query){
        $delete_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

        //Validate Insert
        if($delete_row){
            header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Deleted'));
            exit();
        } else{
            die('Error : ('. $this->link->errno . ') '. $this -> link -> error);
        }
      }

};
```

Ругается непосредственно на функцию `SELECT`. В чём ошибка не пойму. В туториале по которому это делаю всё один в один как у меня, но при этом работает.

Comment: Метод connect() сделайте Singleton'ом.

Comment: Прекрасно, что автор сам нашел ошибку и написал о ней. Только такого уровня вопросы вообще не стоит вываливать на форум, я считаю. Не надо относиться к сообществу как к "отладчику чужого кода".

Comment: Ну я прежде чем написать сюда очень долго сам пытался понять в чём проблема, но не смог, сообщение об ошибке была очень расплывчатое и я не мог понять где же кроется проблема. Спросить не укого, поэтому и написал сюда, что мне ещё оставалось делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем банальная ошибка, точнее опечатка.

Вместо:

```
public function __construct()
```

написал

```
public function __consrtuct()
```

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор не вызывается (из-за ошибки имени метода __cons**rt**uct), а там идет подключение к базе.
Вывод, `$this->link` не инициализируется.

З.Ы. Лучше передавать `$host`, `$port`, `$username` и `$password` в конструктор, а переменные сделать приватными.